# Trying to clone a dribbble but the text isn't coming out right

Tags: html, css, fonts, typography

I'm trying to replicate the left image on this dribbble

https://dribbble.com/shots/2262761-Mobile-Blog-App-Interface/attachments/424147

My question is about the title font. How do they have it displaying as
"

THE

DARK SIDE

OF THE

DIGITAL

NOMAD

"

I tried making the div with the text inside it smaller so it forces the words down but its not coming out the same. I'm assuming they had to manually choose which words would cause a line break? If so how did they do that?

Comment: add a `<br />` after each word.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't assume that what you see on dribble is a screenshot from a working application, it can rather be a proof of concept designed in publishing software such as Adobe Photoshop, Adobe InDesign, GIMP, etc. …

I you want to replicate this example in an HTML page, you should as Toby mentioned in his comment use the `<br/>` tag for each line.

If this is the main title, the code might look like this :

```
<h1>THE<br/>
DARK SIDE<br/>
OF THE<br/>
DIGITAL<br/>
NOMAD<br/>
</h1>
```